# Count Relation in Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I have the following block of code:

```php
$categories = EventCategory::select('id', 'name', 'thumbnail_url', 'slug')
->with(['events' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`sales_end_date`, '%Y-%m-%d') >=  DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')")
        ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') >=  DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')")
        ->count();
}])
->where('is_active', 1)
->get();
```

Now what this does is it returns a list of event categories, however I want it to return a count of all events in each category as well.

The above code just returns all the categories with all their events instead of just the count.

I had something else I was using in my model which worked but I was unable to apply a `where` clause on it, furthermore I didn't want to put `where` clauses n my model in the first place:

```php
class EventCategory extends Model implements SluggableInterface
{
    use SluggableTrait;

    protected $sluggable = [
        'build_from' => 'name',
        'save_to'    => 'slug',
        'on_update'  => true,
    ];

    protected $table = 'event_categories';
    //protected $appends = ['counter'];

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventDetails', 'category_id');
    }

    public function getCounterAttribute() {
        return $this->events->count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($categories as $category)
{
  $category->event_count = count($category->events);
}
```

Your custom SQL should be built into the relation, not your specific instance, and if the relation logic proposed:

```
$query->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`sales_end_date`, '%Y-%m-%d') >=  DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')")
    ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') >=  DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d')")
    ->count();
```

Only applies to one function of the website, then you should build that functionality into a model interface (repository) to "override" the default functionality of the relationship.

Refer to:
[Laravel - many-to-many where the many-to-many table is (part-) polymorph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416872/laravel-many-to-many-where-the-many-to-many-table-is-part-polymorph/32508968#32508968)

Comment: Actually it applies to more than one function of my that's why i do not want to implement it in my model :)

Comment: So there is no way i can return the count without getting all the events in each category first and counting them in a foreach loop?